# sIFR 2.0.7 scaling text instead of wrapping text

Tags: css, fonts, sifr

I am struggling over here.  iSFR is scaling my text to fit on one line instead of wrapping.  Why is this?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
// flash h2 headers
 sIFR.replaceElement(named({
 sSelector:"h2.title, h3.title, #comments h2.comments",
 sWmode: "transparent",
 sFlashSrc:"<?= PATH ?>sites/all/themes/temp/sifr/DIN_light.swf",
 sColor:"#333333"
}));

// CSS
h3.title {
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 color: white;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:26px;
 color: white;
}
```

Comment: Any particular browser? or all of them have the same issue?

Comment: In your "flash h2 headers" can you put this `forceSingleLine: false;` and see what happens?

Comment: tried it already, no change :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It should be:

```
// CSS
h3.title {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use sIFR 3, it tackles this exact issue.